# how to test if tikz library is loaded

Tags: tikz-pgf, programming

I want to write some demo code showing code with examples for tikz.
However I want the resulting pdf to be automatically depended on the tikz libraries and therefore I must test which are loaded.

Is this functionality implemented in tikz already or can I test for the existence of special commands?

EDIT:

Example which shows that the code does not work outside the preamble. I however need code that works everywhere:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{circuits}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\@tikzextension{code.tex}
\def\IfTikzLibraryLoaded#1{%
   \@ifl@aded\@tikzextension{tikzlibrary#1}
}
\makeatother

\listfiles

\begin{document}    
\IfTikzLibraryLoaded{circuits}{is loaded}{not loaded}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When `tikz` loads the library `foo`, it defines the macro `\tikz@library@foo@loaded`. Therefore the following code will do the job:

```
\makeatletter
\def\IfTikzLibraryLoaded#1{%
  \ifcsname tikz@library@#1@loaded\endcsname
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I made a remix of this solution (thanks!) to make it a one-liner that can go inside the document rather than on the preamble. Here it goes:
`\def\CheckTikzLibraryLoaded#1{ \ifcsname tikz@library@#1@loaded\endcsname \else \PackageWarning{tikz}{You forgot to add usetikzlibrary{#1} in the preamble!} \fi }
\CheckTikzLibraryLoaded{circuits}`

Answer (score 8):

you can create a new command based on the definition of the command `\@ifpackageloaded`:

In the example below I provided the new conditional `\iftikzlibraryloaded`
with the syntax:

```
\iftikzlibraryloaded{<name>}%
 {True Code}%
 {False Code}
```

Here the complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\@tikzextension{code.tex}
\def\iftikzlibraryloaded#1{%
   \@ifl@aded\@tikzextension{tikzlibrary#1}
}
\makeatother
\iftikzlibraryloaded{calc}
 {\def\OUTPUT{calc loaded}}
 {\def\OUTPUT{calc not loaded}}

\begin{document}
\OUTPUT
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are not using `\@ifpackageloaded`, at least I see not where. What is `\@ifl@aded` actually doing and what is your meaning of `\@tikzextension` ? Is this code working also outside the preamble?

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech: `\@ifpackageloaded` is defined as `\def\@ifpackageloaded{\@ifl@aded\@pkgextension}`. Do you see what I mean?. A library of tikz has the following syntax `tikzlibrary<Name of Library>.code.tex` and the command `\@ifl@aded` requires two arguments. The first one is the extension.

Comment: Ok, but as far as I know `\@ifpackageloaded` only works in preamble.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech: That's right. In the file `latex.ltx` you can find the relevant part `\@onlypreamble\@ifpackageloaded`. I don't set this.

Comment: Ok, so If I use only `\@ifl@aded` I do not have this proble, correct?

Comment: @matthiaspospiech it s correct

Comment: Well, I tried it and it gave me `! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.` I added my test code to the question.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel `latex.ltx` has `\@onlypreamble\@ifl@aded` too. So this command can't be used after `\begin{document}`. But this is not the problem: files loaded by `\usetikzlibrary` are not listed by `\listfiles`, because they lack the necessary `\ProvidesFile`. Hence no method based on `\@ifl@aded` can work with them.

Comment: @egreg: I didn't see `\@onlypreamble\@ifl@aded` ;-( -- However `\@ifl@aded` works. Why do you think it can't handle that?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel In your case it works because you define `\OUTPUT` in the preamble. Moreover it doesn't work with the `circuits` library, for example (with `calc` it does because the `\ProvidesFile` is in it).

Comment: @egreg: That's really bad. I tested with the wrong library ;-)