# How to define a macro inside a macro via \if?

Tags: tex-core

I need to give specific name to a macro based on a condition.

The first example works, the second does not.

Is using `\csname`/`\endcsname` (i.e., example 1) the only right way? Are there any other ways to make example 2 work?

```
\count255=0
\def\newdef{\advance\count255 by1
 \expandafter\def\csname
  \ifnum\count255=1
    foo%
  \else
    bar%
  \fi
 \endcsname
}
\newdef{hello}
\newdef{world}
\foo\ \bar
\bye
```

```
\count255=0
\def\newdef{\advance\count255 by1
  \ifnum\count255=1
    \def\foo
  \else
    \def\bar
  \fi
}
\newdef{hello}
\newdef{world}
\foo\ \bar
\bye
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your second example, when the `\ifnum` takes the first branch, TeX executes `\def\foo\else...`, which is quite problematic as we'll explain below. Things are similar when the other branch is taken: `\def\bar\fi...`.

## What happens precisely

Let's take for instance the case where the `\ifnum` test is true. In this case, `\foo` gets defined, but not the way you expected. The actual definition is:

```latex
\def\foo\else\def\bar\fi{hello}
```

This is a valid macro definition where the *parameter text* is `\else\def\bar\fi`, and the *replacement text* is `hello`. So, whenever `\foo` is expanded after this definition, TeX wants to see the tokens `\else\def\bar\fi` right afterwards. But in your example, the token after `\foo`'s call is a control space `\`, therefore you get the error:

```latex
./faulty.tex:11: Use of \foo doesn't match its definition.
l.11 \foo\ 
           \bar
Runaway argument?
```

The other case defines `\bar` as:

```latex
\def\bar\fi{world}
```

which, when expanded towards the end of the TeX run, fails for the same reason (`\bye` isn't the same token as the expected `\fi`).

## Remedy

A simple way to fix that is to expand the `\else` or `\fi` at the appropriate time, in order to remove the unwanted tokens from the input stream before TeX gets to execute the `\def` (i.e., before the `\def` from the chosen branch reaches TeX's stomach):

```latex
\count255=0
\def\newdef{\advance\count255 by1
  \ifnum\count255=1
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\foo
  \else
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\bar
  \fi
}
\newdef{hello}
\newdef{world}
\foo\ \bar
\bye
```

This is essentially the same trick as the [classical one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48472/73317) using LaTeX's `\@firstoftwo` and `\@secondoftwo`.

Expanding the `\else` when the condition is true removes all tokens between the `\else` and the matching `\fi` (both inclusive; note that if the condition were still undecided, a [frozen `\relax`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/normal-relax-vs-frozen-relax) would be inserted). Expanding the `\fi` simply removes it. So, in the first case, what is left in the input stream is:

```latex
\def\foo{hello}
\newdef{world}
\foo\ \bar
\bye
```

and in the second case:

```latex
\def\bar{world}
\foo\ \bar
\bye
```

## Going a little further

I said above that if you try to expand the `\else` token when the condition is still undecided, a frozen `\relax` is inserted. In this case, making this become reality only requires adding a percent sign after `\ifnum\count255=1`, because then TeX would continue expanding tokens after the `1` (the 〈number〉 following the `=` sign wouldn't be finished yet) and would therefore expand the two `\expandafter`s *before* this 〈number〉 has been fully read. So, removing the end part of the code that doesn't matter here, the test code could be:

```latex
\count255=0
\def\newdef{\advance\count255 by1
  \ifnum\count255=1% bug here: the second <number> isn't finished!
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\foo
  \else
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\bar
  \fi
}
\newdef{hello}\show\foo
\bye
```

which shows the inserted frozen `\relax` inside `\foo`'s definition:

```latex
> \foo=macro:
\relax \else \expandafter \def \expandafter \bar \fi ->hello.
l.9 \newdef{hello}\show\foo
```

Comment: I added an explanation of precisely what happens in your second example. See also *Going a little further* about the frozen \relax in case you were to put  a percent sign in the wrong place (where it would prevent a 〈number〉 from being finished).

Answer (score 6):

The problem is, as described in Frougon's very fine answer, that conditionals in TeX work in quite a peculiar way: when the test is evaluated true, `\else...\fi` will only disappear as a result of expanding `\else`, which removes everything up to the matching `\fi` (without expansion). When the test is evaluated false, everything up to `\else` (or `\fi`) will be removed (without expansion). A dangling `\fi` will disappear anyway, because its expansion is void.

The method with `\csname` works, because expansion is performed *all the way* until only character tokens remain (other unexpandable tokens will throw a `Missing \endcsname` error), so `\else` and `\fi` will disappear as described above.

Workaround? Since you're doing definitions, expandability is not a concern and you can use Knuth's preferred construction with tail recursion and `\next`.

```
\count255=0
\def\newdef{\advance\count255 by1
  \ifnum\count255=1
    \def\next{\def\foo}%
  \else
    \def\next{\def\bar}%
  \fi
  \next
}
\newdef{hello}
\newdef{world}
\foo\ \bar

\bye
```