# Fail to detect if "external" TikZ library is already loaded

Tags: tikz-pgf

Based on this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48455/163874), I try to detect if a `TikZ` library is already loaded or not.

For a reason I ignore, it cannot detect `external` while it's called in the preambule.

[image]

Adapted MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\@tikzextension{code.tex}
\def\iftikzlibraryloaded#1{%
   \@ifl@aded\@tikzextension{tikzlibrary#1}
}
\makeatother

\iftikzlibraryloaded{external}
 {\def\OUTPUT{external loaded}}
 {\def\OUTPUT{external not loaded}}

\iftikzlibraryloaded{calc}
 {\def\OUTPUTT{calc loaded}}
 {\def\OUTPUTT{calc not loaded}}


\begin{document}

\OUTPUT

\OUTPUTT

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that `tikzlibrarycalc.tex.code`, the source file loaded by `\usetikzlibrary{calc}`, begins with line `\ProvidesFileRCS{tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex}` but `tikzlibraryexternal.tex.code` doesn't contain any use of `\ProvidesFileRCS`.

`\ProvidesFileRCS{<file>}` will eventually call `\ProvidesFile{<file>}`, which makes the test `\@ifl@aded{<ext>}{<file>}` works.

If all you want is to detect if `external` library is *loaded*, then you can detect if any of commands exclusively provided by it is defined, for example

```tex
\ifdefined\tikzexternalize
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
{<loaded>}{<otherwise>}
```

And if you want to further detect if the externalization is *activated*, `\tikzifexternalizing{<true>}{<false>}`, used after `\tikzexternalize`, is at your service.

**Update**

I've added an issue to pgf-tikz, see https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1162. Also I find there're more tikz libraries that lack `\ProvidesFileRCS`, hence `\@ifl@aded` is not a reliable detecter for tikz libraries.

**Update 2**

An example employing [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48472), the accepted answer to the question OP linked.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\makeatletter
% \IfTikzLibraryLoaded{<lib>}{<true code>}{<false code>}
\def\IfTikzLibraryLoaded#1{%
  \ifcsname tikz@library@#1@loaded\endcsname
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

calc: \IfTikzLibraryLoaded{calc}{loaded}{not loaded} \par
external: \IfTikzLibraryLoaded{external}{loaded}{not loaded}

\end{document}
```

Output:

```
calc: loaded
external: loaded
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer I would NEVER have figured out (really...). May I ask you to include your answer in a compilable code ? :)

Comment: [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48472), the accepted answer to the question you linked, which tests if `\tikz@library@<lib>@loaded` is defined, (still) works.

Comment: shame on me but I did not know how to integrate egreg's answer in compilable code :/

Comment: See answer update :D

Comment: Just to give some background, I sometimes need to `\tikzexternalenable` or disable some graphes in my code. I wanted to have an automatic way to include them without errors when I include the same piece of code without externalize.

Comment: A tricky way is to use `\csname tikzexternalenable\endcsname`.